# Getting ReadOnly error when writing data to AWS elastic cache while the cluster is vertically scaled

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, redis-py, elastic-cache

I have a python application that writes some data to AWS elastic cache cluster at a regular interval.

Here's an example script that simulates the functionality of my application. It also replicates the error that I have been facing.

```py
from datetime import datetime
import redis
import time
import sys
import random

class Config:
    default_host = "localhost"
    master_host = "xxx.xx.0001.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com"
    replica_host = "xxx.xx.0001.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com"
    redis_db = 8
    socket_conn_timeout = 10
    request_delay_sec = 0.1

def get_redis_client():
    return redis.Redis(
        host=Config.master_host,
        db=Config.redis_db,
        socket_connect_timeout=Config.socket_conn_timeout,
    )

def get_random_key_value():
    val = time.time()
    key = "test_key_" + str(random.randint(0, 100))
    return key, val

r = get_redis_client()

r.flushdb()

flag = False

while True:
    try:
        if flag:
            print("beat:", time.time())
        r.set(*get_random_key_value())
        time.sleep(Config.request_delay_sec)
    except redis.RedisError as re:
        print(datetime.now(), "Error:", type(re), re)
        flag = True
        # sys.exit()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Stopping loop execution")
        sys.exit()
```

Here are the environment details of my application

- Python(v 3.7.0)
- Redis-py(v 3.5.3)
- AWS elastic cache(cluster mode disabled, 1 master node, 1 read replica)

When I scale my AWS elastic cache cluster vertically and the above script is running, I get the following error for few seconds while the cluster scaling-up is in process and then it goes away.

```sh
<class 'redis.exceptions.ReadOnlyError'> You can't write against a read only replica.
```

AWS docs also states that during vertical scaling process some inconsistencies may occur because of data syncing(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/redis-cluster-vertical-scaling.html)

Has anyone faced any similar issue or can explain why this error occurs during the scale up process? how can it be fixed?

EDIT:
I tried the same thing with a golang script and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Scaling.RedisReplGrps.html

Comment: It states that some inconsistency may occur, but I don't think the error I am getting is related to this

Comment: "You will notice a brief interruption (a few seconds) of reads and writes from the old nodes because the connections to the old nodes will be disconnected." - this might be what's happening

Comment: It's working fine when using a golang based version of above script.